# How to make a limited number of records (single values) easy to compare to for a CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5000 records, two fields of which contain `Categories` and `SubCategories`.  There are only a (small) finite number of possible values.  These are kept in `tblCategory`, `tblSubCategory`, they are not linked (and do not need to be).  Note that the `Categories`/`SubCategories` in the main table do change frequently.

I want to add a flag in my view that checks if the `categories`/`subcategories` in each record are valid by checking the contents of the table.  The `Categories`/`SubCategory` tables will rarely change.

I just want something similar to  `CASE WHEN tblRecords.Category is in tblCategory.Category THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS errCategory`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(Category) 
        FROM tblCategory WHERE 
       tblCategory.Category = tblRecords.Category) > 0 
THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS errCategory
```

Comment: I've accepted THIS answer over the others as in this specific case it is the easiest to implement, I've used it as part of an AFTER INSERT trigger and it will not be called (or required) after the initial insertion (each day) of ~5000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Outer joins might perform better than subqueries:

```
select tblRecords.*,
       case when tblCategory.Category is null 
            then 0 
            else 1 
        end IsCategoryValid,
       case when tblSubCategory.SubCategory is null 
            then 0 
            else 1 
        end IsSubCategoryValid
  from tblRecords
  left join tblCategory
    on tblRecords.Category = tblCategory.Category
  left join tblSubCategory
    on tblRecords.SubCategory = tblSubCategory.SubCategory
```

If you consider null Category/SubCategory valid you need to add appropriate condition to cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. There is some customization work on it .. but is easy stuff .. I do not know exactly what you want to do.

```
select 
  ....
  ,case when cat.found>0 then 0 else 1 end as errCategory
from tblRecords tr
join ......
...........
cross apply (select count(*) from tblCategory tc where tc.Category = tr.Category) cat(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an outer join like this:

```
   select <data>, 
     case when b.Category is null then 1 else 0 end as CategoryError,
     case when c.SubCategory is null then 1 else 0 end as SubCategoryError
   from tblRecords a
   left outer join tblCategory b on a.Category = b.Category
   left outer join tblSubCategory c on a.SubCategory = c.SubCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want a category **not** to be valid? To always keep it valid, just use the proper FK. Ditto for subcategory.

If you really want to be able to store a category that could be temporarily invalid, do it in a field that is **separate** from the field that acts as a child endpoint of the FK. When the time comes to validate it, simply move it to the field covered by the FK.

Comment: My team is responsible for a small portion of a extremely large request system.  What is valid/invalid for the request that we deal with is different to other teams and types of requests, so the main server does not have as much validation as we would like.  We download a snapshot of 'our requests' each morning and upload to our own server.  So what you suggest, whilst proper, is not practical in this case.